# Trouble figuring out how parsed xml is stored - simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, function, simplexml

Let's say my `XML` is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lists>
    <list
        path=".">
        <entry
            kind="dir">
            <name>Assignment1.1</name>
            <commit
                revision="1668">
                <author>netid</author>
                <date>2011-09-07T03:03:58.367692Z</date>
            </commit>
        </entry>
        <entry
            kind="file">
            <name>Assignment1.1/.classpath</name>
            <size>397</size>
            <commit
                revision="1558">
                <author>netid</author>
                <date>2011-09-06T17:00:52.998920Z</date>
            </commit>
      .
      .
      .

    </list>
</lists>
```

And I store it in a `SimpleXML` object using

`$xml_list = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/svn_list.xml');`

How would I access for example, the revision variable containing 1558?

I can't seem to figure it out using a combination of `echo` and `print_r`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML uses a set of classes which implement iterators to work through them, so you can loop through each node using foreach, however the easiest way to navigate the XML once it's loaded is by using [`SimpleXMLElement::xPath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php). To get revision 1558, you can make the following call:

```
$commit = $xml_list->xpath('//list/entry/commit[@revision="1558"]');
```

This will return you the nodes underneath `<commit revision="1558">`, and you can then access them from the `$commit` variable, which extends [`ArrayObject`](https://www.php.net/ArrayObject).

To get the actual content of the `<author>` element, you must do the following:

```
print((string)$commit[0]->author);
```

`SimpleXMLElement` instances need to be cast to a type to expose their actual values.

Also, if you want to dump the content of `$commit` to see its child nodes, the easiest way is to call the `asXml()` method as follows:

```
print($commit[0]->asXml());
```

Comment: may need to reference the first item in the xpath with an index: `$commit[0]->asXml()` as `xpath()` returns an array of SimpleXML elements

Comment: Whoops. This is why I shouldn't StackOverflow at 5am. :)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What about if I was trying to get `name` of the entry with revision 1558? That's not extremely obvious to me as this method seems to be more for getting child nodes, rather than parents

Answer (score 1):

You are facing difficulties because you have error on your XML file , The `</entry>` tag was not closed.

You could traverse like this.

```
<?php
$xml='<lists>
    <list>
        <entry
            kind="dir">
            <name>Assignment1.1</name>
            <commit
                revision="1668">
                <author>netid</author>
                <date>2011-09-07T03:03:58.367692Z</date>
            </commit>
        </entry>
        <entry
            kind="file">
            <name>Assignment1.1/.classpath</name>
            <size>397</size>
            <commit
                revision="1558">
                <author>netid</author>
                <date>2011-09-06T17:00:52.998920Z</date>
            </commit>
            </entry>
    </list>
</lists>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($xml->list->entry[0]->commit->attributes() as $a=>$v)
{
    echo $v;
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
1668
```